# How to display a JComboBox when an item is selected in another JComboBox

Tags: java, sql, jcombobox

I'm trying to display values in `JComboBox B` when I select items from `JComboBox A`. So far, nothing happened when I select a value from `JComboBox A`. Here is my data and code. So for instance, if I select 1 from my `JComboBox A`(paperid), my result in `JComboBox B`(authorid) will be 1,2,4.

[image]

[image]`JComboBox A`

[image] `JComboBox B`

```
private void comboboxAPopupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent evt) { 

    String display = (String) comboboxA.getSelectedItem();
    String sql = "Select authorid from submission where paperid =?";

    try {
        ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1,display);
        rset = ps.executeQuery();

        if (rset.next()){
               String add1 = rset.getString("authorid");
               System.out.println(add1);
               comboboxB.setSelectedItem(add1);
        }

    } catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    }
 }
```

Comment: can you post your JComboBox both A & B's values into question ?

Comment: can you please also explain me if user select 1 from Combo-A then what should be expected to be display into Combo-B ?

Comment: it will display 1,2,4 in combo-B. Basically all the values that belong to combo-A paperid 1. Hope is not confusing.

Comment: correct.. but little bit confusion... you told ComboBox... at a time how comboBox display more than 1 into Combobox-A... it's make me confuse, can you please make it little more clear

Comment: posted some screenshot, hope is clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that I've understood your question at last. You want the result of the query to be charged in the second combobox, don't you?

If that's the case, try this

```
 private void comboboxAPopupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent evt) { 

    String display = (String) comboboxA.getSelectedItem();
    String sql = "Select authorid from submission where paperid =?";

    comboboxB.removeAllItems(); // <- Clear comboboxB

    try {
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, display);
        rset = ps.executeQuery();

        while (rset.next()) {  // <- Include all authors found
           String add1 = rset.getString("authorid");
           System.out.println(add1);
           comboboxB.addItem(add1);
        }

   } catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
   }
}
```

Maybe you have to force a repaint in the container where the JComboBoxes are displayed after the execution of this method. `"myContainer"` is not the variable name, replace with the name of your panel or your frame.

```
   myContainer.revalidate(); 
   myContainer.repaint();
```

Comment: Hey RubioRic, thanks for replying my question. Right now I can only display 1 value. What should I do if I want to display all the values instead. For instance, when I select "1" in comboA, my comboB should give me the result of 1,2,4 instead of just "1".

Comment: @JasonChingYuk Use a "while" instead of an "if". Replace "if (rs.next())" by "while (rs.next())". It should do the trick. It's already in my answer. It should work if there are more than one author related to a paper registered in the DB. Be so kind to accept the answer if that works for you.

Comment: Oh yea I missed that, Thank you so much once again!